# Booting Arch Linux arm on an Android device

Tags: linux, android, arm, arch-arm

I Really think about booting a linux image (WITHOUT GUI Just terminal) in an android device so there are a lot of linux arm images starting by debian , arch , raspberry pi , etc ...
Is that possible on an old device That comes with keyboard like this one
[image: Samsung GT-B5330]

i see a lot of video that they do a virtualization to the linux image (i Don't Want that )
i realy want to install it on the device storage not on SD-CARD
Here is the specification of the phone

```
 Chipset : BCM21654
 Storage : 4GB
 RAM : 512 MB
 Type of processor core : ARM Cortex-A9
 ARMv7
```

the phone is too old

i had found the compatible kernel with that model on [github](https://github.com/bcm216xx/android_kernel_rhea) it will be really god if i can insert the kernel in the image then run it